# Evaluate $\iint_{x<u,y<v, x^2+y^2<1} dx\,dy$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

How can I evaluate the following double integral:

$$\iint\limits_{\substack{x<u,y<v, \\ x^2+y^2<1}} dx\,dy$$

If we didn't have the restrictions $x<u, y<v$ polar coordinates would have worked quite nicely to give $\pi$ , the area of a unit circle, but how do I proceed here?

All suggestions are welcome. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Draw a graph. See how the linear inequalities restrict the area, and you ought to get in Cartesian cords the limits to integrate for separate cases.

Comment: @Macavity Which cases, you have in mind?

Comment: Consider regions partitioned by $-1, 0, 1$ On both axes for $u, v$. Some of these are trivial, and in some cases easier to consider the portion of the circle not belonging to the region being integrated.

Comment: You should be able to geometrically decompose the area being counted by the integral into a disjoint union of rectangles, triangles, and wedges of circles.

Comment: @GregMartin My trouble lies in the fact that $u$ and $v$ might be either greater or less than zero and the regions are different each time (cc @Macavity)

Comment: There are only four cases to consider (three if you use a symmetry). Just do them one at a time. Maybe at the end you'll find a way to combine the answers all together, maybe not.

Comment: @GregMartin I am sorry but I'm having trouble computing it. Would you like to post your solution as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One case is when $u>0$ and $v<0$. Then the region whose area the integral measures is the disjoint union of a rectangle, two triangles, and a sector of a circle.

[image: circle when $u>0$ and $v<0$]

The area of the rectangle is $u|v|$; the areas of the triangles are $\frac12|v|\sqrt{1-v^2}$ and $\frac12u\sqrt{1-u^2}$; and the area of the sector is $\frac12(\arcsin |v| + \frac\pi2 + \arcsin u)$, since the angle of the sector at the origin is $\arcsin |v| + \frac\pi2 + \arcsin u$. So the total area is
$$
u|v| + \tfrac12|v|\sqrt{1-v^2} + \tfrac12u\sqrt{1-u^2} + \tfrac12(\arcsin |v| + \tfrac\pi2 + \arcsin u).
$$

Another case is when $u>0$ and $v>0$. Now the area in question is a sector plus a tall triangle, minus a wide triangle and a rectangle.

[image: circle when $u>0$ and $v>0$]

The area of the sector is $\frac12(\frac\pi2 + \arcsin u - \arcsin v)$, and the area of the tall triangle is $\tfrac12u\sqrt{1-u^2}$; the area of the wide triangle is $\tfrac12v\sqrt{1-v^2}$, and the area of the rectangle is $uv$. So the total area is
$$
\tfrac12(\tfrac\pi2 + \arcsin u - \arcsin v) + \tfrac12u\sqrt{1-u^2} - \tfrac12v\sqrt{1-v^2} - uv. \tag{$*$}
$$

Note that the expression in the first case also equals ($*$), since $|v|=-v$ in the first case. You can check that the formula ($*$) also holds in the two cases where $u<0$.

Comment: Shouldn't $y$ be less than $v$? In the first circle, if we are taking $y$ to be the vertical axis, then $y>v$ isn't it?

Comment: Oh, I misread. Then reflect all the pictures in the $x$-axis and replace $v$ by $-v$....

Comment: I worked out the rest. Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad it was helpful!